# Facebook Custom Tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-tabs

I understand how to create the app for the custom tab.  However when I try to layout the next step it comes back with an error message.  Can someone help me to properly layout the "With URL Redirects".

I know to put the Id number where is says YOUR APP ID and I have also placed the website in the "YOUR URL" position but it doesn't work.  I have watched several videos and they all seem to be prior to the latest FB update.

The problem I am having seems to be coming from the setup for this code below that leads you to the Add Page Tab Dialog prompt. `facebook.com/dialog/pagetab? app_id=YOUR_APP_ID &amp;amp;redirect_uri=YOUR_URL` When I insert the "Your App ID" and Your URL" and hit enter I am receiving a Facebook Error message that says:

> This dialog has been passed a bad parameter. API Error Code: 100 API
>   Error Description: Invalid parameter Error Message: Requires valid
>   redirect URI.

Comment: Bit hard to understand what you are trying to ask here. So this is about the page tab add dialog? What exactly is the error then? Have you paid attention to the limitation on where page tab apps can be used, right on top of the official documentation page?

Comment: So sorry for the difficulty!  The problem I am having seems to be coming from the setup for this code below that leads you to the Add Page Tab Dialog prompt. 
     https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?
app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&amp;redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

     When I insert the "Your App ID" and Your URL" and hit enter I am receiving a Facebook Error message that says.

This dialog has been passed a bad parameter.

     API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

Thank you!

Comment: The redirect URI must match your app settings. Not sure right now if just redirecting anywhere to your app domain works, or if it has to actually be one of the redirect URIs configured for Facebook login (probably not, because a page tab app doesn’t necessarily have to involve login features in the first place.) Just redirecting back to `https://www.facebook.com/` also used to work fine.

Comment: (The `&amp;` needs to be a simple `&` of course, if you call this directly. Only if you put this into HTML, as a link href, it would have to be encoded.)

Comment: Thank you!  I will give that a try and see if it works.